# What is related to the no of instructions a CPU can handle at one time?

Tags: cpu

> Which of the below choices is related to the number of instructions a CPU can handle at one time?
> A) 32bit word size
> B) 3GHz clock speed

I think should be (A). 2^32 instruction at one time?

Comment: $2^{32}$ is in the billions (thousand million). I doubt any computer can execute *that* many instructions *at once*...

Comment: I think the last line needs an overhaul. *What* `should be (A)`?

Comment: Sorry just typo

Comment: Please, define what you mean by "handle" at "at one time".

Comment: @JörgWMittag no of instructions possessed by the CPU in a second

Comment: Please, define what you mean by "possessed". You are only replacing one word with another, but this is not a precise, unambiguous, objective, exact specification.